# Need advice regarding handling updating many-to-many relationships in Entity Framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, many-to-many, ef-model-first

WHAT I HAVE:

Visual Basic 2015, Entity Framework (DBContext), WinForms

MY PROBLEM:

I'm writing a VB 2015 program using EF (*Model-First*, since I'm starting from scratch), and some of my entities have **many-to-many** relationships. I read that in order to add or remove a relationship between an instance of Entity1 and an instance of Entity2, one has to do the following:

'   get entities

```
Dim e1 As Entity1 = query getting an instance of Entity1   'Navigation property: e1.Entity2Collection*

Dim e2 As Entity2 = query getting an instance of Entity2   'Navigation property: e2.Entity1Colection*
```

'   populate collection

```
dbc.Entry(e1).Collection(Function(e) e.Entity2Collection).Load()   'lambda overload
```

*or*

```
dbc.Entry(e1).Collection("Entity2Collection").Load()   ' string overload
```

'   perform update

```
e1.Entity2Collection.Add(e2)
dbc.SaveChanges()
```

*or*

```
e1.Entity2Colection.Remove(e2)
dbc.SaveChanges()
```

The Entry/Collection/Load statement is important  because the relationship won't be properly added/removed unless the collection is populated (another way is to use the Include method in the original query).

**But here's where I'm unsure what to do:**

Suppose Entity1 has a many-to-many relationship with each of *2 or more* other entities--for instance,

Entity 1 is many-to-many with Entity2,

Entity1 is many-to-many with Entity3, and

Entity1 is many-to-many with Entity4

**Do I need to also do:**

```
dbc.Entry(e1).Collection(Function(e) e.Entity3Collection).Load()

dbc.Entry(e1).Collection(Function(e) e.Entity4Collection).Load()
```

**before doing the Add or Remove in order for the above update to work properly?**